# What is the best relationship to use when creating associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am new too rails so I apologize in advance if this is a basic question.

I am creating a Dungeons and Dragons MVC web app using Rails where a Player can log in and create a Character and then that character can be added to a campaign along with other Player created characters. I know I could use a join-table to connect my player model with my character model, but it doesn't seem right using the adventure table as the join table. I've read up on different associations using Active Record but I am still confused. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not a Ruby expert but I think your question is both too vague and too broad as written.  You will get better answers if you can narrow the question down and show what you have tried, what results you expected, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Player = User.

User logs in with his email with gem devise https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

Next the logged in user can create Characters.

User `has_many :characters`.

Character has `user_id`. Character `belongs_to :user`

Answer (score -1):

You can update the models so that a player has_many :characters and a campaign has_many :characters. You will also need to update the database schema for characters as follows: t.references :player : campaign.